# what does the third number in the tuple argument denotes in numpy.zeros((100,100,3)) function?

Tags: python, numpy

`numpy.zeros((100,100,3))`

What does number 3 denotes in this tuple?

I got the output but didn't totally understand the tuple argument.

Comment: The third dimension of the 3D array. You're building a 100x100x3 array of zeros. If you were using `numpy.zeros((W,X,Y,Z))` you would get a 4D array of WxXxYxZ zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will create a 3D array with 100 rows, 100 columns, and in 3 dimensions.